# Check failed: status == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (3 vs. 0) CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM for FASTER RCNN Library

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am testing [Faster Rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn). Installation is fine.
During the installation, I had one issue with cudnn5.1 and I followed the suggestion [here](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/issues/237) and now installation is fine.

Now I test the demo code as

```
./tools/demo.py
```

Then I have error as

```
I1117 09:48:41.011925 12503 net.cpp:51] Initializing net from parameters: 
name: "VGG_ILSVRC_16_layers"
state {
  phase: TEST
  level: 0
}
.
.
.
layer {
  name: "cls_prob"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "cls_score"
  top: "cls_prob"
}
I1117 09:48:41.012234 12503 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer input
I1117 09:48:41.012251 12503 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer input
I1117 09:48:41.012259 12503 net.cpp:380] input -> data
I1117 09:48:41.012271 12503 net.cpp:380] input -> im_info
I1117 09:48:41.328574 12503 net.cpp:122] Setting up input
I1117 09:48:41.328608 12503 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 1 3 224 224 (150528)
I1117 09:48:41.328614 12503 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 1 3 (3)
I1117 09:48:41.328618 12503 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 602124
I1117 09:48:41.328624 12503 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer conv1_1
I1117 09:48:41.328655 12503 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer conv1_1
I1117 09:48:41.328660 12503 net.cpp:406] conv1_1 <- data
I1117 09:48:41.328670 12503 net.cpp:380] conv1_1 -> conv1_1
F1117 09:48:41.676553 12503 cudnn.hpp:128] Check failed: status == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (3 vs. 0)  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is wrong with my installation for this faster rcnn?

I have cuda8.0 and libcudnn5_5.1.10-1+cuda8.0 is installed on Ubuntu16.04. 
I have Qurdo K4200 graphic card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works for me. Since libcudnn5_5.1 is for CUDA7.5. Can check in cudnn's user guide at GPU and driver requirements. So I changed to cudnnv6.0 for CUDA8.0.

Then you may face the issue of

```
Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (8 vs. 0)  invalid device function
```

For that you will need to py-faster-rcnn/lib/fast_rcnn/config.py and change

```
__C.USE_GPU_NMS = True

to 
__C.USE_GPU_NMS = False
```

Then now it works.